# Inverse of a permutation?

Tags: java, arrays, permutation

would someone please explain this example and its answer. I understand if an  array has {3,2,6} then its inverse would be {6,2,3}. Is this what being asked because the piece of code below doesn't seem to achieve this?

Suppose that the array int pi[128] contains a permutation of the numbers 0, 1, ...., 127.

What one or two lines of Java code would you use to efficiently produce the inverse of
pi in the array ip[128]?

**ANSWER:**

```
 for (i=0; i<128; ++i) 
      ip[pi[i]] = i
```

Comment: Interesting permutation but I don't see where that's the "inverse": http://ideone.com/niIUuM - based on my definition that answer is wrong.

Comment: The answer is from an exam assigned by my prof.

Comment: Possibly it depends on how you are interpreting the array `pi` as a permutation. It is supposed to be cycle notation? or is it a mapping where `i -> pi[i]` ? In the latter case, your answer looks like it would be an inverse mapping (i.e. `pi[i] -> i` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know where you saw that answer, because it is wrong.

To illustrate, let's use array of size 4.
With `pi = {3,0,1,2}`, result is `ip = {1,2,3,0}`.
Or `pi = {0,1,2,3}` becomes `ip = {0,1,2,3}`.
Don't know in what definition of the word "inverse", those would be the right results.

Correct answer is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
    ip[i] = pi[127 - i];
```

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @Andreas answer.  The answer you have just copies the array.  I don't see how that can be called "inversing" the array.  I've created a few samples that setup arrays according to the problem (with fewer elements) and print the results.

## Example "inverse"'s the array and prints the result

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         int arrayLength = 10;
         int[] pi= new int[arrayLength];
         int[] ip = new int[arrayLength];
         int i =0;
         for (i=0; i<arrayLength; ++i) 
              pi[i] = i;

         for (i=0; i<arrayLength; ++i) 
              ip[pi[(arrayLength-1)-i]] = i;
         System.out.println("pi: "+Arrays.toString(pi));
         System.out.println("ip: "+Arrays.toString(ip));
    }
}
```

### Result

> pi: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>   ip: [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

## Example based on answer in question

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         int arrayLength = 10;
         int[] pi= new int[arrayLength];
         int[] ip = new int[arrayLength];
         int i =0;
         for (i=0; i<arrayLength; ++i) 
              pi[i] = i;

         for (i=0; i<arrayLength; ++i) 
              ip[pi[i]] = i;
         System.out.println("pi: "+Arrays.toString(pi));
         System.out.println("ip: "+Arrays.toString(ip));
    }
}
```

### Result

> pi: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>   ip: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is wrong (and doesn't even compile).

The `ip` array will contain the *index* of each number, not the "inverse".

In the case where the permutation is ordered, the resultant array will be identical to the input:

```
int[] pi = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] ip = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    ip[pi[i]] = i;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ip));
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Whatever "inverse" means, I wager it does't mean "the same". Your example strongly suggests it means "reverse", which the "answer" clearly does not produce.

---

Based on your question, IMHO your professor lacks knowledge, experience and is not the sharpest knife in the drawer. My advice is to find another teacher as quickly as you can.

Comment: The answer which OP provided is correct. It computes the inverse of a permutation in the mathematical sense. OP wants to *reverse* the permutation, but mistakes this for *inverting* it. `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` is an identity permutation and thus its own inverse, so this result is to be expected. You could have avoided personally attacking OP's professor, as they did provide a solution that really does compute the inverse. They are not at fault.

Answer (score 1):

This is an "inverse permutation" for permutation $\pi$, in the sense any mathematician would use. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InversePermutation.html

Answer (score 0):

An inverse permutation is a permutation which you will get by inserting position of an element at the position specified by the element value in the array.